# <a href using variable in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to include a link in one element which is within a table.

When I do the link without  it's working fine, however when I want to include it as a part of the table it doesn't work.

This line of code works:

```html
for(int i=0;i<tableWeb.size();i++){
  TableBody t=(TableBody)tableWeb.get(i);%>
    <a href="Controller?operation=<%=t.getString1()%>"><%=t.getString1()%></a> 
<%}%>
```

This line of code fail:

```html
for(int i=0;i<tableWeb.size();i++){
   TableBody t=(TableBody)tableWeb.get(i);%>
     <tr><td><a href="Controller?operation=<%=t.getString1()%>"><%=t.getString1()%></a></td></tr> 
<%}%>
```

It seems like the variable part isn't been recognice.

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Are you writing the `<td>`s inside a loop, like `for`? Please post relevant code to understand your problem.

Comment: impossible to tell what is wrong based on your description, but it's absolutely sure that having `<td>` or being without it does not cause the issue.

Comment: Absolute right, I've modified the code and as you said it's inside a loop, anyway I've tried outside a loop and it still having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry guys, it's working fine however when I write this code in Netbeans, I can see a "HTML error".

Answer (score 1):

Table body structure should be

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td> ... </td>
   <td> ... </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Place `<tr>` outside of `for-loop`

```
<tr>  
  for(int i=0;i<tableWeb.size();i++){
    TableBody t=(TableBody)tableWeb.get(i);%>
      <td>
        <a href="Controller?operation=<%=t.getString1()%>"><%=t.getString1()%></a>
      </td> 
  <%}%>
</tr>
```